# How to remove and reset everything about burg, grub and plymouth

Tags: grub2, plymouth, burg

I'm a newbie to Ubuntu, and I'm using 11.10.

I used `super boot manager` and `boot manager`, and I messed a lot with burg, grub and plymouth till that whatever I do there will be no change to burg theme and plymouth theme.

So, I removed `super boot manager` `boot manager` and reinstalled `super boot manager`, but it give me an error when I hit `install burg` button.

How to remove and reset everything about `burg`, `grub` and `plymouth` so I can set a theme for them?

Comment: how do u remove super boot manager help me please

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you remove a package, its configuration files usually stay behind. Use `sudo apt-get purge <name-of-package>` to remove configuration files along with the package.

This may still leave behind configuration files in your home directory, or files you created yourself. You may need to remove those files manually.